# Is there any option to know the sharded entity is re-started by recovery(remember-entity=true)

Tags: akka.net, akka-cluster

I have enabled the Cluster Sharding with remember-entities = true. So when I restart my application entities are getting recovered, but I want to know this entity is recovered or it is newly created, any way to get this?

Answer (score 0):

usually, when persitent sharded actor is created it means that it has been initialized at first. I would suggest to create initialization message for new actor, so inside the actor you can easily detect has it been initialized or not. I think akka .net doesn't have something out of box for it.

For example, suppose your AuctionActor receives two messages:

```
PlaceBid

GetBids
```

If you ask GetBids for actor with id = x, akka .net will check does it exists in cluster, and create it if not. So, when your actor is started, you can't find out has this auction been started or not. You can create third initialization message:

```
StartAuction
```

Then, when GetBids message comes, you can check inside actor has it been initialized or not.